# Python Socket Object

Tags: python

“ A python object provides a public interface to other code that wants to use it but maintains its own private, internal state;Other parts of the system don’t have to care about what is goin on inside the object. ”

Python sockets, Berkeley API, and tcp protocol are 3 layers.

It says the socket object provides a public interface to other code that wants to use it.
Example of other code would be Berkeley API, the python object wants to use the API, not vice versa.
Socket class definition code wants to use the object instance, but no other code wants to use the object, the object was created to call or use other code when it wants without caring what is inside the API.

The object is a function when converted into machine code, calls on the API (berkeley API was coded in C, compiled to machine code and is part of OS),
The API requests methods that are implemented inside the TCP protocol,also was coded in C and compiled to machine code.

Python code uses Cpython to convert it to machine code. They are all converted to machine code by a C compiler or something similar to make communication between layers compatible.
or is it just a coincidence C is involved with every layer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   What is your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like output from something like ChatGPT and isn't really a question

Comment: The first 2 lines is a quote from an online article. I am relating to understand its meaning with an example of python socket object being a public interface to other code. An example of other code could be Berkeley API.

 
The object is an interface to socket class, class to Berkeley API, Berkeley interface to TCP protocol where the socket actually exists. Each layer is linked with calls or interfaces. The code of each software and interface talks with each other in machine code, which was the output of C compiler in every level is not a coincidence, it is for compatibility.

Comment: I know it doesnt make much sense, just for clarity to expand.